# Por qué no me está queriendo dejar eliminar datos? Nestjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

Estoy haciendo un simple CRUD de clientes pero a la hora de borrar un registro no me da un error. Uso de Prisma como ORM

```
clients.serivces.ts 

  async deleteClient(id: number): Promise<boolean> {
    const response = await this.prismaService.clients.delete({
      where: {
        id,
      },
    });

    if (response) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Los clientes tienen relación con tabla de Users

```
clients.controller.ts

@Delete(':id')
  async deleteClient(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number) {
    const response = await this.clientsService.deleteClient(id);
    if (response) {
      return 'Cliente eliminado';
    } else {
      throw new HttpException(
        'Error eliminando cliente',
        HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
      );
    }
  }
```

```
Tabla Clients
 id             Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  name           String
  address        String
  phone          String          @unique
  email          String          @unique
  identification String          @unique
  createdAt      DateTime        @default(now())
  updatedAt      DateTime        @default(now())
  user           Users[]
  subscription   Subscriptions[]
  payment        Payments[]
  active         Boolean         @default(false)
  block          Boolean         @default(false)
```

Cuando hago uso de Postman para eliminar algún registro me sale este error:

**Foreign key constraint failed on the field: `clientId`**

Ese field "clientId" está en la tabla User, pero es raro que me esté dando un error con eso

Answer (score 0):

El error **Foreign key** indica que el id de ese client está siendo referenciado en otra tabla por lo que no permite eliminarlo. Pueden ser las tablas de **users**, **subscriptions** o **payments** la que contengan esta clave foránea.

Deberías primero eliminar las tuplas que referencian a clientId en otras tablas o configurar para eliminarlas en cascada.

Acá hay más info de como agregar el on delete en tu entidad.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/referential-actions

PD: Es mejor práctica manejar las excepciones en el servicio y que el controller solo llame a la función del servicio.